# Navbar .pull-right not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to place a content of my navbar to the far right, but I'm not having any success.

This is what it looks like:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
            <div class="navbar-inner navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar-teste">
                    <a class="brand" href="/">Fiscalização</a>
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>

                                <li><a href="/">Início</a></li>
                                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                                    <form class="navbar-search pull-left">
                                        <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Pesquisar">
                                    </form>
                                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown"  id="menu1">
                                            <a class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu1">
                                                <i class="icon-user "></i>  {{user.username}}
                                                <b class="caret"></b>
                                            </a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="/alterar/dados/usuario/">Alterar Dados de Cadastro</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="{%url mudar_senha %}">Alterar Senha</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/sair/">Sair</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>   
                        </ul>

              </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting your `ul` inside a ul that does not have full width of the page.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
            <div class="navbar-inner navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar-teste">
                    <a class="brand" href="/">Fiscalização</a>
                        <ul class="nav pull-left">
                            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>

                                <li><a href="/">Início</a></li>
                                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        </ul>
                                    <form class="navbar-search pull-left">
                                        <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Pesquisar">
                                    </form>
                                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown"  id="menu1">
                                            <a class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu1">
                                                <i class="icon-user "></i>  {{user.username}}
                                                <b class="caret"></b>
                                            </a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="/alterar/dados/usuario/">Alterar Dados de Cadastro</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="{%url mudar_senha %}">Alterar Senha</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/sair/">Sair</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>   
                        </ul>

              </div>
</div>
```

I have ended the `ul`, to seperate out `form` and the second `ul` tags.  These should not be nested inside a `ul` as this is invalid html.